# issues with device drivers,and ppa packages

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, ppa, hp

i am very new to ubuntu . First try is with ubuntu 14 version. since its my very first try please i need help. Some of my Questions are 
a. which PPA's has best reputation
b. which is the best way to download application software, device drivers etc( my mouse pad is only workinf with clicks no scrolling no gestures etc)

I am using hp probook 4525s .amd v120  processor 64 bits os type. 
help me guys

Comment: Please note: if your title doesn't state a question, you're doing something wrong. Ask separate questions in separate questions. Also, these questions aren't likely to have definite answers so they really aren't very useful - try to come up with more specific questions to which objective answers are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quite like downloading software using:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I tend to stick with the repositories that come as standard unless I have a specific need. So can't help with that question.

There is an xinput command that you can use for tweaking input devices.

```
xinput list
```

Then use one of the names to show the properties for what you are interested in:

```
xinput list-props "Device Name"
```

Then you can set the properties to values you specify:

```
xinput set-prop "Device Name" "Property Name" parameter1 parameter2
```

I've also got problems with a touchpad. But I'm trying to reduce the area that is sensitive.

I can't help if it is a driver issue.

Becareful with xinput I've been trial and erroring settings to solve an issue I have. It would be wise to take a copy of the settings as they are before changing incase you make things worse.

I managed to disable my touchpad but was fortunate enough to have a copy of the original settings.